# ftp client reads incomplete messages from server

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

This is my code simple ftp client i can connect to server login but my program reads random incomplete messages from server sometimes they are complete but sometimes it reads only few bytes and i dont know what to do pls help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 5000

int main()
{
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
  int my_socket, passive_socket, sock, len, m = 0, bytes;
  char buf[BUF_SIZE], i[BUF_SIZE];

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = 0;

  if ((sock = getaddrinfo("ftp.linux.cz", "ftp", &hints, &result)) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", gai_strerror(sock));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (rp = result; rp != NULL ; rp = rp->ai_next)
  {
    if ((my_socket = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol))
        == -1)
      continue;
    if (connect(my_socket, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
      break;
    close(my_socket);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(result);

  read(my_socket, buf, BUF_SIZE);
  printf("%s", buf);

  len = strlen("USER anonymous\r\n");
  write(my_socket, "USER anonymous\r\n", len);

  read(my_socket, buf, BUF_SIZE);
  printf("%s", buf);

  len = strlen("PASS secret\r\n");
  write(my_socket, "PASS secret\r\n", len);

  read(my_socket, buf, BUF_SIZE);
  printf("%d\n", bytes);
  for (int n = 0; n < bytes; n++)
    printf("%c", buf[n]);

  len = strlen("EPSV\r\n");
  write(my_socket, "EPSV\r\n", len);

  read(my_socket, buf, BUF_SIZE);
  //printf( "%s", buf );  

  for (int n = 39; n > 0; n++)
  {
    if (buf[n] >= 48 && buf[n] <= 57)
    {
      i[m] = buf[n];
      m++;
    }
    else
    {
      i[m] = '\0';
      n = -1;
    }
  }

  printf("%s\n", i);

#if 0
  if ((sock = getaddrinfo("ftp.fit.vutbr.cz", i, &hints, &result)) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", gai_strerror(sock));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (rp = result; rp != NULL ; rp = rp->ai_next)
  {
    if ((passive_socket = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
        rp->ai_protocol)) == -1)
      continue;
    if (connect(passive_socket, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
      break;
    close(passive_socket);
  }

  read(passive_socket, buf, BUF_SIZE);
  printf("%s", buf);

  len = strlen("NLST\r\n");
  write(my_socket, "NLST\r\n", len);

  read(passive_socket, buf, BUF_SIZE);
  printf("%s", buf);
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `bzero(buf,BUF_SIZE);` to make sure your buffer is clean each time

Comment: **Closely** ***read*** the man-pages for read()/write() and **learn** that those two functions **do not** necessarily receive/send as much **bytes** as they were **told** to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data expected or a terminator had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an **essential necessity**.

Comment: i tried to clear buffer but still same and to this loop for example we have message with 5 lines one loop read first one and we go to another loop and how the server knows that he must send us second line?

Comment: I changed your commenting out via `/**/` to a disabling of the sources via `#if 0 ... #endif` as the formatting tool then understands that *disabled* code is code also.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assume that read *will* read the whole response in once, it can read less, it can read `BUF_SIZE` bytes, but not more during one call.

Your program clearly lacks a clean parser. You should be *reacting* appropriately to what you're reading, which could be an informational message, a warning, an error, or whatever.

The best possible advice I could give you is to look into the [`State Machine Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), if you'd like to roll you own parser for the `FTP` protocol, and into `Lexical Analyzer` and [properly built parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser) in order to do so.

In this manner you will ultimately be able to build powerfull, and robust networking applications.

Comment: but how i know that i have readed the whole message is server sending EOF?

Comment: IIRC, the server does not close the connection. It sends if I remember correctly a `\n` or a `\r\n` at the end of each messages.

Comment: so i need loop until i find \n right? isnt \n for linux and \r\n for windows?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on what the protocol states for this case (what does happen if a message that is part of command has a `\n` in the middle of it ?). As said in my answer, what you basically need is taking a deep look at the RFC 959 and implement accordingly the `states` in which your parser can be in, and in which states it transitions at each reception of a character.

Comment: I've made a quick wireshark capture of a FTP session on my computer, and every command are appended by a `\r\n` in my case. You should do the same for educational purposes, if you doubt of a particular feature or behaviour, this tool could be your better friend.